# how to round corner of an image

Tags: iphone, ios

In order to round the corner of an image, I am doing the following

```
UIImageView     *myView     =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[myView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xcode_57X57"]];
myView.layer.cornerRadius      =   10.0;
myView.layer.borderWidth       =   1.0;
myView.layer.borderColor       =   [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
myView.layer.shadowRadius      =   8;
```

However, what I got is the corners of myView are rounded but the corners of an image.
The image below shows my issue.

If you encountered this problem before, please advice me on this.

[image]

Comment: Check out my answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921594/is-it-possible-to-add-a-border-style-to-a-uitableview-not-bordercolor-borderwi/9921875#9921875 . And also take look at the link in that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to clip subviews:

```
myView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
```