# UITableView Stacked/Shadow Background

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to make a UITableView look as though it's on top of a stack of papers. I did a similar version of this using UIView by overriding `drawRect`, but with UITableView's complexity, I believe it will be more involved than it was with a standard UIView. If I use a stretchable image, the stretched bits won't line up. What would be the best way of achieving something like this?

Comment: You can refer my answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921594/is-it-possible-to-add-a-border-style-to-a-uitableview-not-bordercolor-borderwi/9921875#9921875. It will help you to set shadow background effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Shadow, you can use the CALayer, as in the example below.

```
tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.f;
tableView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = .6f;
```

For the stack impression, i would add some views with same shadow borders beneath the table view.